# How to setup inertia on my project, gives me an error when I try and load the login page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm trying to setup Inertia to use in my Laravel project but it gives me errors? Where is my mistake?

I installed Inertia with this command 
`composer require inertiajs/inertia-laravel`

followed the instructions on the github page and added `@inertia` to my app.blade.php like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="{{asset("/image/logo2.png")}}">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

@inertia

</body>
</html>
```

in my Login Controller

```
 public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Auth/Login');
    }
```

in my routes/web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

This is the error I get:

the lines that is highlighted is the `@inertia` which show up as this
`<div id="app" data-page="<?php echo e(json_encode($page)); ?>"></div>`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a frontend adapter like `inertia/vue`?

Comment: @CaddyDZ this is what I installed https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/tree/v0.1.3

Comment: You need a frontend adapter as well, like https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-vue

Comment: @CaddyDZ I've now installed that, and it doesn't give me that erroe but now i get a blank page? Instead of the login form I have in Auth\Login.vue

Comment: You also need to set it up in webpack in order to use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@inertia` blade directive is working but not rendered because you need to install the frontend adapter

```
npm install @inertiajs/inertia @inertiajs/inertia-vue
```

Set it up in `webpack.mix.js`

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const path = require('path')

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .webpackConfig({
    output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
        '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
      },
    },
  })
```

And initialize it in Vue `resources/js/app.js`

```js
import { InertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(InertiaApp)

const app = document.getElementById('app')

const pages = {
  'Auth/Login': require('./Pages/Auth/Login.vue').default,
}

new Vue({
  render: h => h(InertiaApp, {
    props: {
      initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
      resolveComponent: name => pages[name],
    },
  }),
}).$mount(app)
```

Comment: I've tried this and get this error: 
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './Auth/Login.vue'

Comment: Where is your `Auth\Login.vue` login form located? full path please

Comment: I fixed it, I have fixed the routing problem I have the Login like this resourses/js/Pages/Auth/Login.vue, so I changed the resolveComponent in app.js like this: resolveComponent: name => import(`@/Pages/${name}`).then(module => module.default),

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: If I wanted to implement Element-ui would I do it the same way?

Comment: ElementUI is based on Vue so you don't have to change anything